# for /f reg query finding the subkey which contain my value

Tags: batch-file

I want to find the parameters of the wifi cards remotely on many notebooks.

The Key is `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` but the subkey is not the same for every notebooks, depending the driver and the others networkcards.

Sometimes the subkey is `0012`, `0013` or `0007`. I need to find the right subkey by filtering the *mediatype (0x10) and after having collected the subkey display the driverdesc. and some other values.

Is there a way to find the subkey which contain my value?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use an appropriate tool or API for this. The command

```
wmic /node:host1 nic list brief
```

will list the NIC parameters of the (remote) host "host1". You only have to filter the results for WiFi NICs and to get the information you want.

You can easily embed calls to WMIC in Powershell (which is available in Windows XP and up). Even for parsing the output I would not recommend DOS batch anymore.